# How can I create my own ROS C++ library?

Tags: ros, c++, package, libraries, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello All,

This might be a repeat question (although I checked out some of the recommendations that ROS Answers asked me to look at while typing the title of this question, but they didn't seem relevant). Here goes.

So I have a C++ header file called "force_torque.h" (I had issues with this, but thanks to @jbohren I was able to fix those) and I want to convert it into a ROS library. So basically, I want it to be a valid ROS package, yet I also want other ROS packages to be able to depend on this package. So far, I have just been able to create a new package using 'roscreate-pkg'. Now I have a feeling that I need to modify "CMakeLists.txt" somehow, but I don't know how. Is there any good ROS tutorial on how to do this? Or if it could be described here on this question below, I would be very grateful.

Thanks, and all help is greatly appreciated!

Nishant

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/58295/how-can-i-create-my-own-ros-c++-library?/) by [Nishant](https://answers.ros.org/users/2440/nishant/) on ROS Answers with karma: 143 on 2013-03-15

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In [rosbuild](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosbuild), to build the library you use `rosbuild_add_library` [shown here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosbuild/CMakeLists#rosbuild_add_library), which is similar to the standard CMake `add_library` function. Then to make it available to other ros packages, you add the library linker arguments to a  `<cpp>` export tag in the package's manifest.xml [shown here](http://www.ros.org/doc/independent/api/rospkg/html/manifest_xml.html#export-cpp).

In [catkin](http://www.ros.org/wiki/catkin), you use the normal `add_library` CMake function to build the library. Then to make the library available to other ros packages, you add the library target to the `LIBRARIES` arguments of a call to the `catkin_package` CMake macro, [shown here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/catkin/CMakeLists.txt#catkin_package.28.29).

---

Originally posted by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) with karma: 5809 on 2013-03-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 10

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Nishant](https://answers.ros.org/users/2440/nishant/) on 2013-03-19**:
@jbohren : Thanks! I'll follow the links that you have provided, and see where it takes me. I'll post any roadblocks that I hit on this thread itself. Thanks once again!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[jbohren](http://answers.ros.org/question/58295/how-can-i-create-my-own-ros-c-library/?answer=58315#post-id-58315)'s answer is good.  The wiki also provides some additional [examples](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosbuild/CMakeLists/Examples#Building_a_library) that show how to set up your CMakeLists.txt for different needs.

Alternatively, you could use the technique shown [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/Wrapping%20External%20Libraries) to simply make an existing library available to the ROS system.  For linking, dependencies, etc.  That link suggests this method is deprecated, but I haven't found good documentation on the recommended replacement method.

---

Originally posted by [Jeremy Zoss](https://answers.ros.org/users/3925/jeremy-zoss/) with karma: 4976 on 2013-03-17

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2013-03-17**:
I updated the link on the tutorial page to point to the new Bloom Tutorial: http://www.ros.org/wiki/bloom/Tutorials/ReleaseThirdParty

**Comment by [Nishant](https://answers.ros.org/users/2440/nishant/) on 2013-03-19**:
@Jeremy Zoss: Thanks Jeremy! These examples look good! They should help me get started.
@tfoote : Thanks for the link update, I'll check that too.